# How to denote the minimal bounding curve of two intersecting function curves?

Tags: functions, notation, curves

If there are two functions $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$, $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, how could I denote the minimal bounding curve of these functions? (See the green dotted line on the figure.)
[image]

I'm looking for an expression like $h(x)=minbound(f(x),g(x))$ but I don't know the correct notation for this (if it exists at all).

Answer (score 1):

The common notation for this is $h(x)=\min(f(x),g(x))$. In a brief form, $h=\min(f,g)$.

One can say that $h$ is the minimum of $f$ and $g$, or, to avoid confusion with "minimum of a function", that $h$ is the lower envelope of $f$ and $g$.